# HANA: Nested procedure calls break cursors?

Tags: hana, hana-sql-script

When executed against HANA 102.5, the following batch

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DUMMY( message nvarchar(254) )
AS
BEGIN
/* Do nothing */
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE cur_test
AS  CURSOR cur FOR
    SELECT 'code' FROM DUMMY;
    code NVARCHAR(64);
BEGIN
    OPEN cur;
    CALL DUMMY( 'Start' );
    WHILE 1 = 1 DO SEQUENTIAL EXECUTION
        FETCH cur INTO code;
        BREAK;
    END WHILE;
    CALL DUMMY( 'Finish' );
    CLOSE cur;
END;

CALL cur_test;
```

fails with the error:

```
SqlScript: Unsupported type of lhs:CUR:unknown type
```

Why does this happen?  Notice that when I remove either call to `DUMMY` it works.  When I comment the `FETCH` statement it works as well.  Removing the `WHILE` loop and leaving the body alone also makes the error disappear.

Comment: If a declare the same procedure with `SEQUENTIAL EXECUTION` the error disappears.

Comment: Which SAP HANA revision are you working with? I just tried your code against a rev. 112  and received no error.

Comment: I am on 102.5.  Of course, since HANA parallelizes everything by default it may not know which `CALL` to execute first, so `SEQUENTIAL` solves the problem. I wonder how 112 decides it. Thank you, Lars.

Comment: In fact HANA doesn't simply parallelize _everything_ but instead analyses the dependencies between statements and builds data flow graphs internally to ensure consistency. Since I cannot reproduce your problem, I don't know what causes the error.

Comment: Thank you, Lars.  I shall return to this problem when we upgrade to a later HANA version.